# Can I play the cello without pronation of the bow hand?

Tags: cello, physical-limitations, bowing

I would like to learn to play cello, but I have a mini-disability that prevents me from turning my right hand down (palm-down, or [pronation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronation)) or up (palm-up, or suspination).

**How much is this going to get in the way of handling the bow?
How important is pronation in the mechanics of bowing?**

Additional info:

- I can approximate rotation of the hand by altering my grasp on the
  bow (fingers) and lifting my elbow.
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cello_technique#Right_hand_technique) says that

  > The transmission of weight from the arm to the bow happens through the pronation (inward rotation) of the forearm

but then, can I work around it with the aforementioned ‘cheats’, or would I lose too much in dexterity or sound quality?

- My left hand is fine.

Comment: because you are used to using your hand that way, while you may hold the bow differently to others I will happily assure you can get many hours of enjoyment out of it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IANAMPT (music physical therapist), so take this as encouragement rather than direction.

I would not let any physical disability short of losing your arm :-)  stop you from trying to learn the cello.  Find a decent teacher who can either work with you directly or refer you to a music-oriented physiotherapist to figure out a functional bow grip position that won't injure you.  What really matters is the ability to hold the bow in the correct 3 angles (around all three x,y,z axes in space) with proper pressure and so on.  If it takes a strange grip, or even some custom grip-adapter piece of hardware, so be it.

Go for it.

Comment: i agree, go for it. many musicians have been limited in some physical way but have made awesome music. I am not a cello history buff, but Richie Havens comes to mind on guitar, and there are countless others.

Comment: What does IANAMPT stand for?

Comment: I encountered a professional musician recently whose fingers only reach the first joint.  It is amazing to watch him play piano.   You'll be OK.

Comment: @Cullub  there's an ancient IntarWebz  abbreviation "IANA..." meaning "I am not a" whatever.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft that's a good acronym to know.  Otherwise when someone tells you they're not a lawyer you might be very very confused at first (and unlikely/hesitant to Google the acronym)

Comment: Even losing your arm shouldn't stop you if you really want to learn. Prosthetic limbs are pretty amazing these days.

Answer (score 5):

While I have not played cello, I do (too infrequently) play upright bass.  For upright, there are different ways of holding the bow.  First is French, which is more palm down.  And German which is more palm up.

I have played both ways, and for me I prefer the German style bows.  I feel that it gives me better control and is more comfortable for my hand, wrist and arm.

I don't know if they make a German style cello bow, but the technique may work for you.

I agree with the other posts about finding a good teacher.  Any good teacher will not force you into a painful position.  If you experience pain, then you wont' want to play and that is not what anybody wants.

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea about German bow holding! It does look possible for my hand. A teacher also suggested I try the viol, but then it's suspination that I can't do. I'll definitely give your solution a try!

Comment: [Viol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola_da_Gamba) players (most of which I believe are actually cellists) use in fact a backhanded style similar to German bass bowing. I once tried this on cello and it felt really weird, though it can certainly be used for old music. Using an actual bass bow is also not completely absurd – I myself use a light (French) bass bow a lot these days. You need to take a bit more care not to “squeeze the tones to death”, but with a bit practise you do also get a bit of extra oomph in the lower registers.